# Comment traduire "What is being talked about" en francais?

Tags: grammaire, traduction

## Problem

I am trying to translate the following paragraph. My problem is with the section that is highlighted in bold.

> Entity linking is the task of linking a word in a piece of text, to an
> ‘entity’ or ‘concept’ from a knowledge base . It
> allows us to automatically **detect what is being talked about in a
> document, as opposed to seeing what words it is composed of.**

---

## Translation

La désambiguïsation des entités consiste à lier un mots dans un document textuel à une entité ou concept dans une base de connaissances. Cela nous permet de detecter automatiquement **de qui** on est en train de parler dans le document. A l'opposé de voir de quels mots est constitué le document.

---

My confusion is because of `as opposed to seeing what words it is composed of.`

- Is the following translate correct? Should we say **de qui** or **de quoi**?
- Is there a better translatation?

Thank you.

Comment: You can translate it par "De quoi le document parlait" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the relevance of your translation. It seems to rely a lot on automatic word swap.
Here's what I suggest :

Relier les entités consiste à lier un mot apparaissant dans un texte à une "entité" ou un "concept" existant dans une base de connaissance. Ceci nous permet de déceler/détecter/deviner de manière automatique **le contexte** d'un document contrairement à l'analyse des mots dont ce document est constitué.

"De qui" is used for people. For abstarct concepts and objects, "De quoi" should be used.

Comment: thank you @randomhopeful this translation is great. It's much clearer now